# Poisson processes for tossing a marble

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Norm, while sitting at the bar, rolls a marble towards the wall and sees how close the marble can get to the wall before it stops rolling. The tosses for a Poisson process having rate $\lambda >0$. The distance from the wall at which a marble, rolled at time t, stops rolling is a random variable with density function $f_t(x)=\frac{2(1+tx)}{2+t}, 0\leq x\leq1$, where $x$ is measured in inches. (a) Assuming these random variables are independent and independent of the Poisson process, find the distribution of $X(t)$, the number of tosses that are within a distance of $\frac{1}{2}$ inch from the wall. (b). Suppose that after a marble is tossed, it is picked up after a random amount of time has passed with cdf G, independently of all other marbles. Find the distribution of $Q(t)$, the total number of marbles on the floor at time t that are within $\frac{1}{2}$ inch from the wall.

I am not sure about my thinking process. I would really appreciate any feedback! Thank you!

For point (a) I am thinking that $X(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda \cdot \int_0^t f_s(1/2)ds= \lambda \cdot t$.
For point (b): From (a) we have that the tosses that make the marble land 1/2 inch from the wall form a Poisson process with expectation $\lambda t$. We partition this process into $Q(t)$=the number of such marbles that are still on the floor by time t and $Y(t)$ = the number of such marbles that "left " the floor by time t. Then by the Infinite Server Queue we get that the distribution of $Q(t)$ is Poisson with expectation $E[Q(t)]=\lambda t \int_0^1 1-G(t-s)ds$.

Comment: For (a), you're integrating over the wrong variable, time. You should be integrating over the distance to obtain the time-dependent rate of the process $X$. For (b), you don't get a Poisson process, since the process isn't memoryless.

Comment: Hi Joriki, I'm afraid I need more clarification if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer. It would be easier if you tell us where this problem came from (for context) and in what form you want the distribution of $Q$ to be specified (since it can't be specified as a Poisson process with time-dependent rate).

Comment: The problem came from a set of problems that I study for one of my exams. The school posted them for us to have to practice. I am not sure what book came from. I believe the cdf or pdf of Q(t) will be enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cdf or pdf of $Q(t)$"? $Q(t)$ is a time-dependent process with non-trivial correlation over time. Do you want the marginal distribution for each $t$?

Comment: It looks like the way I thought about the problem is off and I can't step away from it to be able to understand your comment/questions.  Maybe if you briefly write down your chain of thoughts it will make It more clear to me.

Comment: The tossing process is a Poisson process with time-independent rate $\lambda$. The process $X(t)$ is also a Poisson process, but with time-dependent rate $\lambda\cdot p(t)$, where $p(t)=\int_0^\frac12f_t(x)\mathrm dx$ is the time-dependent probability of tossing a marble within half an inch of the wall. (You didn't specify the spatial support of $f_t(x)$, but I assume it's $0\le x\le 1$, since that would make the normalization come out right.) By contrast, $Q(t)$ isn't a Poisson process: A Poisson process is memoryless, wheras $Q(t)$ depends on the past.

Comment: That is, whether a marble is tossed at $t$ is independent of the past, and whether it lands within half an inch of the wall at $t$ is independent of the past, but whether a marble is picked up at $t$ depends on the past, since this happens with some given density $G'$ after the time it was tossed. Thus, whereas the time-independent rate $\lambda$ is sufficient to characterize the tossing process and the time-dependent rate $\lambda\cdot p(t)$ is sufficient to characterize $X(t)$, $Q(t)$ cannot be characterized so simply, since the correlations with the past would have to be described.

Comment: Perhaps by "the distribution of $Q(t)$" you mean the marginal distribution for $Q(t)$ at each time $t$. If so, these marginal distributions don't fully characterize the process $Q(t)$, since they don't contain the correlations between the counts at different times.

Comment: You are right about the support of $f_t(x)$, I made that change. I believe that what they meant by saying that "the amount of time has passed with cdf G, independently of all other marbles" is that these times are independent random variables with cdf G. And thus, we could use the Infinite Server Queue and find the distribution of Q(t) (I am looking at this time as the service time in the $M/M/\infty$ process). It might just be that question b is poorly written.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying point (a)!

Comment: The times it takes for different marbles to be picked up are independent, but the time a marble is tossed and the time it's picked up aren't independent. The former marks an increment in $Q(t)$, and the latter marks a decrement in $Q(t)$. Thus the probability of a decrement in $Q(t)$ is not fully determined by the current value of $Q(t)$, as it would be in a standard server queue with exponentially distributed service times (unless $G$ happens to be an exponential distribution).

Comment: I start seeing the picture of what you mean. Then, Q(t) seems to be a chain that we could maybe characterize with a generator matrix... Thank you for taking time explaining me this problem.

Comment: If by "chain" you mean a Markov chain: No, a Markov chain is also memoryless. The generator matrix of a Markov chain describes instantaneous transition rates dependent only on the current state. The point of the above was that you can't characterize $Q(t)$ like that because the transitions aren't determined by rates dependent only on the current value of $Q(t)$, but by when marbles were tossed in the past.

Comment: I didn't mean Markov Chain; I know it can't be one since our future value depends on past data.

Comment: I see, sorry. What kind of chain were you thinking of? I only know generator matrices in the context of Markov chains.